Can I repeat link labels several times on a web page without hurting SEO by using meta attributes?
I have a page with about a dozen resources. Each resource has a title and a description, then links to play a video tutorial, go to a lesson on the topic, and to visit the documentation pages. The three assets: video, lesson and docs article share the same title.
So this is how I'd structure it:
"Setting up foo with widget name"

Watch tutorial >
Take Lesson >
View Documentation >

The problem is, that for SEO, having the link labels repeat a dozen times on the same page is considered bad practice, and I was asked to spell everything out.
But I think that for a user, seeing the same long title 3 times with just a small differentiation is a bad experience.
For example:

Setting up foo with widget name video >
Setting up foo with widget name lesson >
Setting up foo with widget name documentation >

See how ridiculous that is?
I was hoping maybe I can put something inside the anchor tags that would house the richer keywords. But so far my research on the topic was inconclusive as to whether that's a good option.
Any ideas? Thank you!

But yes, you're right, it would definitely look ridiculous.
It would make it clear that it wasn't done for people.

Here are a few ideas that come to mind.
First option — use hidden keywords in the aria-label and/or title attributes. Something like keeping the visible labels as “Watch tutorial,” but adding more descriptive text in the aria-label, like “Setting up foo with widget name video.”
Second option — stick to your original idea and just vary the descriptions to keep things diverse, as you initially wanted.
And as a bonus, you can mark everything up with Schema.org to ensure search engines have no issues understanding your content.

Thank you for your reply. I was not familiar with Schema site, I will look into it. I may use the aria label and title as a last resort if I don't find an elegant way.

Outside of general seo impacts, this is also a recommended way to have the same click text with multiple destinations as per the WCAG to ensure compatibility with screen readers and assistive devices. https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Techniques/aria/ARIA8.html

Keyword Saturation & Distribution and the Problem with Repeating Patterns
Search Engines want to see search terms that are appropriately scattered in your content, but if they see them too much, they may penalize you for Keyword Stuffing.
So if your whole page is:
<h1>Foos & Widgets</h1>
<label>Setting up foo with widget name video >...
<label>Setting up foo with widget name lesson >...
<label>Setting up foo with widget name documentation >...
<hr>
<label>Changing foo with widget name video >...
<label>Changing foo with with widget name lesson >...
<label>Changing foo with with widget name documentation >...
...

or
<h1>Foos & Widgets</h1>
<label aria-label="Setting up foo with widget name video">video >...
<label aria-label="Setting up foo with widget name lesson ">lesson >...
<label aria-label="Setting up foo with widget name documentation ">documentation >...
<hr>
<label aria-label="Changing foo with widget name video">video >...
<label aria-label="Changing foo with widget name lesson">lesson >...
<label aria-label="Changing foo with widget name documentation">documentation >...
...

Then your page will SEO very poorly for Foos and Widgets because you will be penalized for clearly trying to manipulate the algorithm by just saying the same keywords over and over again with no content to back them up.  So anytime you have highly repetitive content like this, it is best to NOT include your key terms in them because those terms will be ignored as being part of a repeating pattern instead of keystone terminology.
Instead the structure you should aim for is more like this:
<h1>Foos & Widgets</h1>
<h2>Setting up foo with widget name</h2>
<p><!--A brief description about the topic.--></p>
<label>video >...
<label>lesson >...
<label>documentation >...
<hr>
<h2>Changing foo with with widget name</h2>
<p><!--A brief description about the topic.--></p>
<label>video >...
<label>lesson >...
<label>documentation >...
...

or
<h1>Foos & Widgets</h1>
<h2>Setting up foo with widget name</h2>
<p><!--A brief description about the topic.--></p>
<label aria-label="Setting up foo with widget name video">video >...
<label aria-label="Setting up foo with widget name lesson ">lesson >...
<label aria-label="Setting up foo with widget name documentation ">documentation >...
<hr>
<h2>Changing foo with with widget name</h2>
<p><!--A brief description about the topic.--></p>
<label aria-label="Changing foo with widget name video">video >...
<label aria-label="Changing foo with widget name lesson">lesson >...
<label aria-label="Changing foo with widget name documentation">documentation >...
...

When it comes to repeating your key terms, the ideal is to put 1-3 variations of it in your meta-description, once in your meta-title, once in your <h1>, and variations of it in your <h2>s and then only minimally sprinkled around in the rest of your content.  Google understands this to mean that the entire logical structure of your page is dedicated to discussing Foos & Widgets which is much more informative than a page that just says Foos & Widgets over and over again; so, it will sooner return the page that looks more informative.
Making Unique labels: SEO vs WCAG-2
On top of this, using unique labels or titles to further define what the labels are for is useful for WCAG-2 compliance, but WCAG-2 compliance is not automatically going to improve your SEO.  WCAG-2 is a series of standards that relate to how usable your site is for people with various disabilities like impaired vision, color blindness, deafness, etc.
Claims that say that WCAG-2 compliance makes SEO better rely on indirect factors of SEO.  Google does not inherently care if a site is WCAG-2 compliant or not.  If your site has a significant number of users that show up and leave because things like color contrast, font size, confusing buttons, and flashing graphics make it hard or annoying to use, then this will increase your bounce rate and drops your SEO, but as long as your site is already usable and easy to understand by 99.9% of people, you will not see a measurable change in bounce rate by just adding unique labels; so, their presence or lack there of will not have a meaningful impact on your SEO... though it may be legally required depending on what country or industry you are working in.
Because you are asking about SEO and not WCAG-2, it is your Bounce Rate that actually matters here.  You have to ask what is more likely to confuse and drive away users.  Long and specific labels like "Setting up foo with widget name video >" or short labels like "video >".  In this specific case, the shorter labels will actually be easier to interpret for human users which will increase your engagement and improve your SEO.
The recommendation to use meta continent (like aria-labels) to distinguish same labels can help a page's SEO if you do not already have good key term saturation, but if your page is already highly saturated with your key term, it could have counterproductive results; so, while it is typically a good idea, it's not alway the best course of action.  This is why it's always important to make sure your pages have enough informative body text to balance out your repetition of key terms.  The only way to tell for sure if the aria-labels will help is to A/B test them and measure your SERPs for each choice.

Thank you for your comprehensive answer. It seems I can't win here. I either suffer from keyword stuffing or from non descriptive hyperlinks. Do I understand correctly? Note that the topic names will be varied throughout the page, and there could be some documentation titles that will be slightly different than the video titles if that helps.

@pitzki If you need this page to SEO well, having good plaintext descriptions in the  tags will be important.  Keyword Stuffing is a ratio of how many words you have to how many times your keywords are mentioned.  Ideally your keyword should be about 2%  of the content; so, if your descriptions are long enough and are not themselves keyword stuffed, then they will keep the repetitive aria-labels from harming your SEO without sacrificing WCAG-2 compliance.

Infact, having a bit more text is almost always a good thing.  There is an old rule of thumb that a page should have at least 300 words to SEO well.  While this is not explicitly true, having a decent word count is a good way to reduce bounce rates and control for Keyword stuffing which means it is usually true as a matter of consequence.

Thanks. Yes, there is a useful blurb before.
